# How to add personal apt sources?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a decent number of debian packages I've compiled myself, that I keep on a personal build server.  I want to be able to use `apt-get install` to install these but am unsure how to point to all the work that I've done and whether that work should be structured in any other way than a big directory of `*.deb`s.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb ssh://192.168.11.20:22/opt/mystuff/mydebs"
sudo apt-get update
```

Does it still make sense to suffix with `trusty main`?  Are those just additional subdirectories to get to the relevant debs directory?  I'm digging around here and that seems to be the case:

http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial in the official Documentation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal